# Understanding id_partition in Paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, paperclip

I'm using Paperclip to store audio files in AWS.

The files path has an id_partition component (spanning 3 directories).

How does this field is calculated?

I want to be able to track the file from my rails module (or DB entry)

Thank you

Answer (score 26, accepted):

paperclip [id_partition](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/blob/master/lib/paperclip/interpolations.rb#L162) method prepend '0' to ID of ActiveRecord instance to make it of length 9 characters.

i.e `12 would be converted to 000000012`, then it simply splits this string into three chunks and joins these chunks with `/`

interesting reads on id_partition http://37signals.com/svn/archives2/id_partitioning.php

Comment: the difference is that basecamp partitioned the folder names of the record's id, meaning each record could have 32K files. In paperclip it is used as the attachment's folder, meaning that you can have up to 32K styles, but still can have up to 999,999,999 items, which is considerably less than what integer (most primary keys) allow. Am I making sense?